# Как пишется "легкоране(н/нн)ый по двое" ?

Tags: орфография

Как пишется "легкоране(н/нн)ый по двое" ?
Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Comment: Кто по двое? Странная фраза!

Comment: @ernest00 Уважаемый участник, после знаков препинания нужно ставить пробелы.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для ernest00.
Контекст неверный, такого не может быть. поэтому буду говорить только о слове легкораненные. Второй корень никак не влияет на количество Н в прилагательном-причастии. 
Поэтому дальше о слове раненый-раненный. От глагола ранить. Это глагол двувидовой (что делать - ранить, что сделать - ранить), поэтому если слово ранить без приставок или зависимых слов - пишем с Н, часть речи отглагольное прилагательное (или существительное).
Если есть зависимое слово или приставки, кроме НЕ - пишем с НН, часть речи причастие.

Иногда разграничение страдательных причастий и образованных от них прилагательных (тем самым выяснение вопроса о написании нн–н)  производится не по формальному признаку, а по смысловому. Например, в предложении Будучи раненным, солдат оставался в строю слово раненный – причастие и пишется с двумя н, несмотря на отсутствие при нем приставки и пояснительных слов: оно сохраняет глагольное значение. (В силу отсутствия формальных признаков в школе практически не рассматривается и за ошибку не считается).

Для behemothus 
В правилах орфографии у нас принята все-таки некая стабильность. Кроме того, они все более или менее объяснимы. Правило о Н и НН в причастиях вообще-то простое: в полном причастии НН, в кратком Н. Вся сложность в умении отличить причастие от отглагольного прилагательного, далеко не каждый может почувствовать "глагольность...", соотнесенность с действием  или качество. Поэтому были сформулированы 4 формальных признака причастия: приставка, кроме НЕ, совершенный вид, зависимое слово, суффиксы -ова-, ева-, -ирова-. Если эти признаки есть, то пишем НН и часть речи определяем как причастие. Это такой методический прием орфографистов -методистов.  Как теоретик грамматики  Вы сколько угодно можете дискутировать по поводу части речи (а писатели, наделенные хорошим языковым чутьем, писать, как им хочется, показывая тем самым эту самую глагольность, соотнесенность с действием или, наоборот, с качеством), но орфографические нормы имеют у нас статус закона, они строго кодифицированы, и мы им следуем. (Да, при упоминании о смысловом разграничении  - см. первую части ответа -  всегда приводится пример только со словом раненый)

К сожалению, надо констатировать, с краткими формами отглагольных причастий и прилагательных у них так стройно не получилось.

Answer (score 1):

Легкораненый пишется с одним н. Или с двумя, но тогда "легко раненный".
А вот "по двое" он вряд ли пишется. Ну или с большим трудом.

~~~~~~~~

Это тот случай, когда запомнить проще, чем объяснить.
Если подходить с позиции "школьной логики", то раненый - прилагательное, с прилагательным возможно слитное написание. А раненный - причастие, слитное написание невозможно, т.к. глагола "легкоранить" или подобного не существует.

Но по большому счету в современном языка разница в значениях между "раненый" и "раненный" не просматривается ни под каким микроскопом и поддерживается главным образом постулируемой различной синтаксической ролью. Прилагательное якобы не может образовывать распространённый оборот (пресловутые "зависимые слова"). Хотя в текстах встречается сплошь и рядом: "Я тяжко раненный при операции, - хмуро подвывал Шариков", МАБ "СС". Застрелите меня, если кто объяснит с позиций ортодоксальной грамматики, откуда тут взялось причастие. 
Короче, повторюсь, запомнить проще.

Comment: Почему так?

Comment: > А по смыслу там прилагательное, ибо показывает свойство объекта, а не действия

Ничего не понял. Очень часто причастие или причастный оборот - определение. Т.е. является х-кой объекта (субъекта), а не действия. А действие, извините, определяет деепричастие.

Answer (score 1):

> Легко раненные по двое, по трое брели по открытой, среди полей, пыльной дороге.

(Каверин. Два капитана (1938-1944))

Вот это изначальный текст.

~~~~~~~~

> откуда тут взялось причастие.

См. http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/34.htm §52.п.2.

Comment: А ларчик просто открывался.
Тут ещй и субстантиват. Хотя по большому счету этот пример только ещё раз показывает, какая каша с этит причастиями и прилагательными. Не в языке, в в головах у ортодоксальных грамматистов.

Comment: @behemothus, Вы все на свете попутали. Если я правильно понимаю. 

>Застрелите меня, если кто объяснит с позиций ортодоксальной грамматики, откуда тут взялось прилагательное. 

раненный - это причастие ("тяжело раненный снарядом"), а раненый - это отглагольное прилагательное ("Раненый шел домой", "раненый солдат"). В предпоследнем примере это слово выполняет функцию вообще существительного (никто ведь не будет спорить, что "больной", "столовая" - существительные?)

Comment: Это-то я знаю. Вы мне по смыслу объясните, почему в примере у Булгакова должно быть причастие.
Я к тому и веду, что прилагательное "захватывает" часть грамматических функций причастия. 

ЗЫ Я пока процитированный вами текст правил, сам уже "поплыл", сейчас восттановил стройность мысли.

Comment: Насчет прилагательного. "Способный к музыке", "больной гриппом" - чем не обороты с прилагательными и зависимыми словами?

Comment: Держите попугаев.

Вы меня не поняли. Я не жалуюсь на не знание раздела грамматики, я утверждаю, что здесь современная грамматика отстаёт от жизни.

Если с раненными не понятно, вот вам ещё примеры.

Яйцо, вареное в мешочек,  
Подвода, груженая лесом,  
Волосы, стриженые ежиком.  
и т.д.
Во всех случаях прилагательное "вытесняет" законное причастие.
В примере из Булгакова по смыслу должно, в принципе, происходить то же самое. И только традиция застваляет считать, что там причастие.
Только там ещё субстантиват путается.

Comment: Яйцо оставьте в покое. Говорим же "яйцо в "мешочек" без прилагательного.

> Во всех случаях прилагательное "вытесняет" законное причастие.

Я думаю, что 50-на-50. Примеры можно найти для обоих вариантов. Вероятно, процесс действительно идет в сторону превращения причастий в прилагательные.